# How to use a Blob object as parameter for MapSqlParameterSource in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, blob

There is the table mentionned below :

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE
(
   ID_DEMAND             NUMBER NOT NULL ,
   FILE_BLOB BLOB
) ;

ID_DEMAND   FILE_BLOB
---------------------
12          (null)
```

i'm trying to update a "BLOB" field in my Oracle DB using this procedure :

```
create or replace FUNCTION UPDATE_BLOB(
  P_ID_DEMAND IN TABLE.ID_DEMAND%TYPE,
  P_FILE_BLOB IN TABLE.FILE_BLOB%TYPE
)return number
IS

BEGIN

  UPDATE TABLE
  SET FILE_BLOB = P_FILE_BLOB
  WHERE ID_DEMAND = P_ID_DEMAND;


  return 1;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
     return 0;

END UPDATE_BLOB;
```

First, i'm reading a file like that :

```
int idDemand = 12;
File file = new File("C:\\file.xls");
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInput);
```

And, next, i prepare my parameters :

```
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(bytes);
final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("P_ID_DEMAND", idDemand);        
params.put("P_FILE_BLOB", blob);
```

After executing the procedure with simpleJdbcTemplate (from spring) :

```
final BigDecimal li = callFunction("UPDATE_BLOB",BigDecimal.class, params, SOURCE.BASE);
```

Definition of callFunction :

```
public static BigDecimal callFunction(String functionName,Map <String, Object> parameters, Source datasource) throws Exception{
Compteur compteur = new Compteur();
compteur.start();
final SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcCall(DataSourceHelper.getDataSource(datasource));
configureTemplateForFunction(functionName, simpleJdbcTemplate);
final MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValues(parameters); 
if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
    infoFunction(functionName, parameters);
}   
FutureTask<BigDecimal> future =
    new FutureTask<BigDecimal>(new Callable<BigDecimal>() {
    public BigDecimal call() {
        return simpleJdbcTemplate.executeFunction(BigDecimal.class,in);
    }});
executor.execute(future);

BigDecimal out = future.get(TIMEOUT_MAX_IN_SECONDES, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
compteur.stop();

if (log.isInfoEnabled()){
    log.info("Execute : " + functionName + " -- duration --> " + compteur.getTime());
}
return out;
}
```

i'm getting an error `Unknown column type` for the BLOB parameter. I tried to edit my procedure and my code to only use an INTEGER parameter and it worked.

**EDIT :** I finally used a CallableStatement because apparently there is no other way of doing want i wanted.

Comment: Have you tried using oracle.sql.BLOB instead of SerialBlob (or just byte[])?

Comment: For the byte array, i did it and same error. And for oracle.sql.BLOB i'm already using it in this example, the SerialBlob just convert the byte array to blob

Comment: SerialBlob returns a instance of java.sql.Blob, maybe you could try with oracle.sql.BLOB

Comment: I don't know how to use it. I can't import it, it is considered as deprecated : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/BLOB.html

Comment: Yeah it's deprecated. Sometimes using it solves the problem but if you are using Spring I agree there should be better approaches. I've never use SimpleJdbcCall, but reading about it, I've seen that people declares the type of the params using something like this: SqlParameter("in_param_1", Types.BLOB). Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Working for my

```
    @Autowired
    private DataSource ds;

    @Test
    public void testLeePdfs()
    {

        SimpleJdbcCall mySimpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(ds)
                .withSchemaName("MYSCHEME")
                .withCatalogName("MYPACKAGE")
                .withProcedureName("MYSTOREWITHBLOB")
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("ParameterWithBlob", Types.BLOB));

        File fileFromDisk = new File("c:\\test.png");

        try( FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileFromDisk))
        {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put( "ParameterWithBlob", new SqlLobValue( fis, (int)fileFromDisk.length()) );
            mySimpleJdbcCall.execute( new MapSqlParameterSource(map));
        }catch( IOException e)
        {
            LOG.error("Fail io operation ", e);
        }
..
}
```